# Can't leave comment on BLOG post

Tags: 2013, blog

On our system, users are unable to leave comments on BLOGs. Even the creator of the blog post can't leave comments. There is no "Add a Comment" box underneath the blog post at all.

Has anyone ever seen this before? I've been going crazy trying to solve it.

[image]

Comment: Any updates on this matter? We have the same issue.

Comment: No sorry nothing yet. We've actually put the problem aside for the moment to focus on other issues.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you created a sub-site as a Blog called News?! Well that is what I have done anyway.  You need to go to that page and then into the permission setting and assign CONTRIBUTE right.

For the info: the contribution right will allow the user to

- add comments
- manage categories
- manage comments
- manage posts

This is way too much of permissions!

Therefore, go to Manage posts  (as admin) and in there go to manage permissions > set unique permission and remove the user group with the contribute permission :)

This removes the BLOG TOOL from the right side and the users can comment at same time. However, user cannot create new posts!

PS: Might bee too old this topic, but might be useful to someone

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the permissions for the comments list? Under site contents there should be a comments list and you need to make sure this inherits from its parent site.

Comment: Yes, I have checked the permissions for the comments list. Comments list is inheriting permission from parent. Inside parent I have a visitors group with read permissions. On comments list I have added a group with contribute permissions, because I want only certain people to comment a post. Still the same issue. People don't see the comment section, even the site collection administrator can't see this section and therefore leave a comment.

Comment: I've looked at permission as well and everything seems to be set up correctly there.